# Stratifying multiple columns for cross-validation

Tags: r, partitioning, cross-validation, r-caret

There are many ways I've seen to stratify a sample by a single variable to use for cross-validation. The `caret` package does this nicely with the `createFolds()` function. By default it seems that `caret` will partition such that each fold has roughly the same target event rate.

What I want to do though is stratify by the target rate and by time. I've found a function that can partially do this, it's the `splitstackshape` package and uses the `stratified()` function. The issue with that function though is it returns a single sample, it doesn't split the data into k groups under the given conditions.

Here's some dummy data to reproduce.

```
set.seed(123)

time = rep(seq(1:10),100)
target = rbinom(n=100, size=1, prob=0.3)

data = as.data.frame(cbind(time,target))

table(data$time,data$target)

      0  1
  1  60 40
  2  80 20
  3  80 20
  4  60 40
  5  80 20
  6  80 20
  7  60 40
  8  60 40
  9  70 30
  10 80 20
```

As you can see, the target event rate is not the same across time. It's 40% in time 1 and 20% in time 2, etc. I want to preserve this when creating the folds used for cross-validation. If I understand correctly, caret will partition by the overall event rate.

```
table(data$target)

  0   1 
710 290
```

This rate of ~30% will be preserved overall, but target event rate over time will not.

We can get one sample like this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
train.index <- stratified(data,c("target","time"),size=.2)
```

I need to repeat this though 4 more times for a 5-fold cross validation and it needs to be done such that once a row is assigned it can't be assigned again. I feel like there should be a function designed for this already. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but I just had the same problem and I couldn't find another solution. In case anyone else needs an answer, here's the solution I'm implementing.

```
library(data.table)
mystratified <- function(indt, group, NUM_FOLDS) {

  indt <- setDT(copy(indt))

  if (is.numeric(group)) 
      group <- names(indt)[group]

  temp_grp <- temp_ind <- NULL
  indt[, `:=`(temp_ind, .I)]
  indt[, `:=`(temp_grp, do.call(paste, .SD)), .SDcols = group]

  samp_sizes <- indt[, .N, by = group]
  samp_sizes[, `:=`(temp_grp, do.call(paste, .SD)), .SDcols = group]

  inds <- split(indt$temp_ind, indt$temp_grp)[samp_sizes$temp_grp]

  z = unlist(inds,use.names=F)
  model_folds <- suppressWarnings(split(z, 1:NUM_FOLDS))

}
```

Which is basically a rewriting of `splitstackshape::stratified`. It works like the following, giving as output a list of validation indeces for each fold.

```
myfolds = mystratified(indt = data, group = colnames(data), NUM_FOLDS = 5)

str(myfolds)

List of 5
 $ 1: int [1:200] 1 91 181 261 351 441 501 591 681 761 ...
 $ 2: int [1:200] 41 101 191 281 361 451 541 601 691 781 ...
 $ 3: int [1:200] 51 141 201 291 381 461 551 641 701 791 ...
 $ 4: int [1:200] 61 151 241 301 391 481 561 651 741 801 ...
 $ 5: int [1:200] 81 161 251 341 401 491 581 661 751 841 ...
```

So, for instance the train and validation data for each fold are:

```
# first fold
train = data[-myfolds[[1]],]
valid = data[myfolds[[1]],]

# second fold
train = data[-myfolds[[2]],]
valid = data[myfolds[[2]],]

# etc...
```